# Relationships based on category

Tags: relationships, low-search, related-entries

I am trying to just get relationships based on a certain category (accommodatie_lesaanbod_relatie). However this doesn't seem to do anything. All relationships are returned without any regard to the category it's in.

```
{exp:webs_low_search:results
    collection="accommodatie"
    categories_in_children_from_channel="les"
    disable="member_data|pagination|categories|category_fields"
    parse="inward"
    location_based="n"
    radius="{location_filter_radius}"
    limit="5"
}

    {stash:channel}{channel_short_name}{/stash:channel}
    {stash:channel_name}{channel}{/stash:channel_name}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:item}accommodatie-{count}{/stash:item}

    {stash:subtitel}{accommodatie_stad}{/stash:subtitel}
    {stash:afbeelding}{accommodatie_afbeelding}{/stash:afbeelding}
    {stash:href}/{channel_short_name}/{url_title}{exp:webs_filter_url}{/stash:href}

    {accommodatie_lesaanbod_relatie category="5"}
        {exp:stash:append_list
            name="list-les-1"
            parse_tags="yes"
            save="{cache_collectie_h}"
            scope="{stash:_scope}"
            replace="{cache_replace_h}"
            refresh="{cache_refresh}"
        }
            {stash:title}{accommodatie_lesaanbod_relatie:title}{/stash:title}
            {stash:item}les-{accommodatie_lesaanbod_relatie:count}{/stash:item}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/accommodatie_lesaanbod_relatie}

{/exp:webs_low_search:results}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `category` parameter was only added to the native Relationships tag pair in 2.7.3 (released yesterday). ([See changelog.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-3))

Comment: Ah, how stupid of me. I checked the docs today and didn't notice the new release :D. Thanks.

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20632/relationship-in-expression-engine